# Store Big Dictionary Restrict Memory

Tags: python, memory, pickle, disk, shelve

I have an extremely big dictionary that I need to analyze.

***How the dictionary come to existance?***

The dictionary is a pivot table of log file. 
I have a snapshot of inventory everyday and right now I have the snapshots for the past month.

each snapshot looks like this:

```
2013-01-01 Apple 1000
2013-01-01 Banana 2000
2013-01-01 Orange 3000
....
```

And then, I group all the records by the product name and plan to do the time series analysis later. 
The output I have looks like this:

```
{
 Apple:[(2013-01-01,1000),(2013-01-02, 998),(2013-01-03,950)...],
 Banana:[(2013-01-01,2000),(2013-01-02, 1852),(2013-01-03, 1232)...]
 Orange....
}
```

As you know, assuming you have years and years of inventory snapshots and very wide inventory breadth... This dictionary turns out to be huge. The whole 'GROUPING' process happens in memory and the size of the dictionary exceeds the memory limit.

I am wondering how to restrict the memory usage to a specific amount(say 5GB and I don't want to disable the server for normal usage) and do the work on the disk.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851438/how-to-store-a-big-dictionary) is a very similar question to mine but following the 'BEST VOTED' answer, the memory is still quickly eaten up after I change the loop number to a real 'Big data' size.

So any example that truly doesn't kill memory would be appreciated and speed is not that import to me.

(Note, there are several ways to optimize the data structure so that the dictionary size could be reduced but... the inventory snapshots are not periodic and some of the products have different number of snapshots so 'MATRIX' idea may not work)

Comment: Why not use a sql database instead?

Comment: I am doing most of the work using standardIO in which case a database breaks this 'rule' a bit.   I want to have a file with human readable contents sitting there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, I would suggest you stop using a dictionary and [`import sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), or you're going to be reinventing the wheel implementing optimizations that databases already have.

To get started quickly, [`Elixir`](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki) is a very decent and practical ORM.

Comment: Seems like database is truly the way to go. So I have to loop through every log record and do something like 'insert into table apple values (...)'  and after all the insertion... loop through all the distinct products and fetch all the records for each product and do the analysis one by one?

Comment: @B.Mr.W. You may be able to do some of the analysis using SQL instead of Python for better performance.